# Typescript: Best practices for partial entities

Tags: typescript, typescript-partial

I have a pretty basic question but couldn't find anything about it, maybe I'm missing the keywords.

Imagine a basic entity interface and class:

```js
interface EntityInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

class Entity implements EntityInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  constructor(data: EntityInterface) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = data.name;
  }
}
```

When I load my data from the server I simply create an Entity with

```js
const entity = new Entity(serverData); //serverData looks like {id: 1, name: 'foo'}
```

But of course I also want to create a new Entity and send it to the server to persist it.
I can't instantiate the empty entity and fill it, because the members have to be defined:

```js
const entity = new Entity(); // => Error: constructor needs parameter
const entity = new Entity({}); // => Error: EntityInterface requires an existing id and name
```

I know about the Partial utility in Typescript, but I couldn't figure it out how to use it for the current usecase.
I thought about setting the EntityInterface parameter in the constructor to Partial.
But I definitely want the required-members-typings when having entities loaded from the server.

Then I thought about having a "ServerEntity" class (with required members) and a "PartialEntity" class with optional members.
But I do not want to define the members for each class since the members differ only in whether they are required or optional.

I thought about extending the "PartialEntity" from the Entity class, but this would still require the proper data for the constructor:

```js
class PartialEntity extends Entity implements Partial<EntityInterface> {}

const entity = new PartialEntity({}); // => Error: EntityInterface requires an existing id and name
```

I'm pretty sure there is a solution/best practice to this problem, but I can't figure it out by myself.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

How about using a static method to create an "empty" object that you can then persist? Something like the below

```
class Entity implements EntityInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  public static EMPTY(): Entity {
     return new Entity({id: node-uuid.v4(), name: defaultValue });
  }

  constructor(data: EntityInterface) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = data.name;
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like this

`someService.persist(Entity.EMPTY());`

Comment: Yes I also thought about simply providing some dummy/default values, but is this the right approach? What would you enter for the id? There is simply no id until the entity is persisted. I could set the id to null, but then I would have to modify the EntityInterface to `id: number | null` and that sounds messy, doesn't it? I think the `Partial` utility exists for this kind of usecase, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: would it be an option to mark the id as an optional field? (just to be clear, in the interface we´d have id?: number

Comment: yes, that's a possibility, but then the fields would sometimes be optional unnecessarily: Persisted entites always have an id, but with optional fields I would have to code like `entity.id as number` or `if (entity.id !== undefined) {}`. It's possible, but I don't think that's the way to go. In fact, that's how I'm doing it currently ;)

Comment: another way i can think of is simply assigning a random unique values if its not provided, with something like node-uuid, (since i assume the first save to the server is a new entity, it would make sense) only downside is that unique ids created using node-uuid are strings and not numbers

Comment: Sido note: my IDs are actually strings, I chose `ǹumber` for this example.
So you would basically set the ID for new entites on the frontend? I think thats an antipattern since the backend is responsible for persisting in the database and generating the ID, even if the ID is a random guuid. Besides, what would you set `name` to? I dont want to set `name` to an initial value if it`s a new entity

Comment: From what you are describing seems like what you really want is to chose to have a backend service to create and return the new entity for the UI. Depending what the entity actually is it might be reasonable for UI to generate the guids, for example it is common for enterprise apps to let UI generate correlationIds in requests etc